# No pattern and password lock screen in AOSP ROM for HiKey 960

Tags: aosp

In AOSP ROM for HiKey 960, I can only choose swipe or none as lock screen.

How do I get the option to choose pattern or password?

Comment: Feel very welcome in this forum, thanks for closing the question after 11 views, so no one else could see it and be angry about it. Turns out the question was not about   *writing and publishing Android apps, writing custom ROMs, and other topics that are primarily of concern to developers* after all; but nobody knew that until it was answered.

Comment: Apologize for a late welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange, a Q&A site focusing on Android end-users solving their issues. We tend to be wary about questions related to building/customizing ROM since usually end-users can't really help. However, if the question can be reworded to be asked from end-user POV instead (like, mentioning an already baked custom ROM that has the same issue), then it might have a chance to be reopened.

Comment: it there a way we could make this a good question for this forum by asking for system-lockscreens which could be installed on a random rooted device or aosp device in /priv-app/ - do you see such a possibility for this crowd?

Comment: After some consideration, I took a chance to make the question at least end-user-y (While Android.SE doesn't really accept building ROM, it allows questions on flashing available ROM, including AOSP ROM). At the very least, consider reposting the answer with sources/references.